# Libraries for generating URL of uploading files in Django

Tags: python, django, url, project, libraries

Need to develop a project for file uploading and **generating its(files's) URL, which could be shared**. Are there any particular **libraries** or simple means in **Python**,(Django) that would be handy and efficient.?
~ *Newbie* trying a Herculean Task~ Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of this is done for you in the [Django-backed version](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload) of this excellent [JQuery file upload app](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Try out a demo of the original [here](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Comment: Yeah, Jquery file upload app does work good. But now, the problem is I need to develop that kind of an application, which uploads files and also generates some url which could be shared , and url should exist only for some time. ANY leads in this matter would be very helpful.

Comment: Take a look at the code in the Django back-end for JQuery file upload on github: https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/fileupload/models.py It uses django.db.models.permalink to create the url. See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.permalink

Answer (score 1):

No. Since the `Storage` used may not even save the actual files on the filesystem, there is no [universal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.url) way to generate a URL to them. You will need to create a view that gets passed a key that it can use to identify the record that has the file field, then you will need to [respond with the file contents yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+download+file).

Comment: @Vazquez-Abram Thanks for your response, but I would be glad if it were more elaborate and understandable to a newbie. And is it not possible even if we use some other server other than the default django server. Please do guide :)